# What is the best deployment approach for WPF applications with local database?

Tags: sql-server, wpf, application-design, mdf

- I want to make a **WPF** application that exists in **one directory** including all files that it needs: **.exe**, **.mdf** database, **.xml** config files, etc.
- the application should work **no matter** what directory it is in so that it supports this **scenario**:

  - person 1 **executes** the application in `c:\temp\wpftool.exe`
  - the application reads and writes to the `c:\temp\wpftool.mdf` **database**
  - person 1 **zips** up that directory and sends it to person 2 via e-mail
  - person 2 **unzips** it to `c:\Users\jim\documents\checkout\wpftool.exe`, the application reads and writes to the same database in that directory (`c:\Users\jim\documents\checkout\wpftool.mdf`)
  - person 2 **zips** the directory up again and sends it back to person 1 to **continue** making changes on it

**What is the best way to create a WPF application that supports the above scenario?**, considering:

- there should be **no** **hard-coded** database connection strings
- what is the best **deployment** **method**, click once? or just copy the .exe file out of the /release directory?
- **reasonable security** so that users have to log in based on passwords in the database, and if a third person happens to intercept the e-mail, he could not easily look at the data in the database

Answer (score 1):

Some points on the database side:

Assuming the "New user" already has SQL installed, they'd need to attach the (newly copied) database. Besides having sufficient access rights to attach a database, your application would need to configure the call to include the drive\folder containing the database files. If your .exe can identify it's "new home folder" on the fly, you should be able to work that out.

Define "reasonable security". Any database file I get, I can open, review, and ultimately figure out (depends on how obscure the contents are). Can you obfuscate your data, such as using table "A" instead of "Customer"? Would you really want to? The best possible security involves data encryption, and managing that--and in particular, the encryption keys--can be a pretty advanced subject, depending on just how "secure" you want your data to be.

Answer (score 1):

For the database, I would look into using the ["user instance" feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504.aspx) in SQL Express. Combined with the |DataDirectory| substitution string support it makes it very easy for your application to get hooked up.

In all honesty I have *not* deployed a ClickOnce app leveraging this approach myself yet, but I just thought I would bring it to your attention because it's what I would look into myself if I was building something like you described.